# How to split an integral exactly in two parts

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This question is a by-product of a conversation with Theo Buehler in [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/do-results-from-any-lp-space-for-functions-hold-in-the-equivalent-ellp-spa/31890#31890) to this answer. Let's settle definitions.

**Definition** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. We say that $X\in \mathcal{F}$ is an *atom* if $\mu(X) > 0$ and its only subset of strictly positive measure is $X$ itself. $\Omega$ is said to be *non-atomic* if no atoms exist.

So in a non-atomic measure space we can always split a measurable subset into smaller ones. Now the question is: have we got some control over this splitting? Can we split something *in exactly two parts*? I'm especially interested in the following.

**Question** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a non-atomic measure space and $f \in L^1(\Omega), f \ge 0$. Are there measurable and disjoint $A, B \subset \Omega$ such that $A \cup B = \Omega$ and

$$\int_A f(x)\, d\mu= \int_B f(x)\, d\mu=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega f(x)\, d\mu?$$

Comment: My answer below was deleted; it runs into annoying problems with subsets of measure zero and fixing it seems to basically require doing what Byron Schmuland suggests.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've revised my answer, as I felt the original did a disservice to the OP and the reader
by downplaying the difficulty of the question. It is a nice problem!

The OP is correct that a non-atomic probability space is wonderfully flexible,
and can be split into pieces with specified probabilities. The crucial fact
needed is that we can always split such a space exactly in two. 
That is, there exists $B\in{\cal F}$ so that $\mu(B)=1/2$. Finding $B$ is not 
trivial, but not terribly difficult. It is often assigned as an exercise in a measure theory class. 
An argument using Zorn's Lemma can be found [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Atom_%28measure_theory%29&oldid=408858789#Non-atomic_measures).
Also, it is Exercise 2.17 (page 31) in *Probability and Measure (2nd edition)* by
Patrick Billingsley, and Corollary 1.12.10 (page 56) in Volume 1 of Bogachev's *Measure Theory*.

Once we have this result, we can create a uniform$(0,1)$ random variable on our space
as follows. Start with a set $B(1/2)\in{\cal F}$ with $\mu(B(1/2))=1/2$. 
Splitting $B(1/2)$ and its complement  exactly in two, we get a partition of four sets each with 
$\mu$ measure of $1/4$. 
By induction, you can create a collection $B(q)$ indexed by the dyadic rationals $q$ so that $q\leq r$ 
implies $B(q)\subseteq B(r)$ and $\mu(B(q))=q$. 
Now define $U(\omega)=\inf (q : \omega\in B(q))$. The random variable $U$ has a uniform$(0,1)$ 
distribution, i.e. $U$ is a measurable map to Lebesgue space $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mu) \to  ((0,1),{\cal B},\lambda)$.
 Any splitting (or representation) on $(0,1)$ can now be pulled back to $\Omega$ via $U$.

A consequence is that $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mu)$ can serve as the "common probability space"
 for [Skorokhod's representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem). In particular, for any probability measure $\nu$ 
on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ 
so that the law of $Y$ is $\nu$. Choosing $\nu$ to be a 
discrete measure shows that you can split $\Omega$ into a finite 
or countable collection $B_i$ of measurable sets with $\mu(B_i)=p_i$ for any 
$\sum_i\ p_i=1$ and $p_i\geq 0$.

My answer (and the comments) here [Construction of "pathological" measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30025/construction-of-pathological-measures/30028#30028) may also help.

Granted, you don't really need the full power of Skorokhod's result.
But it is worth remembering that any non-atomic probability space is "universal" in this sense.

I cannot resist the temptation to also note that the representation extends to Polish spaces. 
For any probability measure $\nu$ on a Polish space $(S,{\cal B}(S))$, there exists a 
random variable $Y:\Omega\to S$ on your non-atomic space so that the law of $Y$ is $\nu$.

Finally, about question 2? 
We either have the trivial case $\int_\Omega f(x) \mu(dx)=0$, or 
$$\mu_f(B)={\int_B f(x) \mu(dx)\over \int_\Omega f(x) \mu(dx)}$$ defines a new non-atomic 
probability measure which can split $\Omega$ exactly in half.

Comment: @Jonas T: Thanks, I've fixed it now.

Comment: @Byron: This is very nice indeed and I'm thinking at it. However, I'm having some problems with the proof of (2). I understand that the class of measurable $B$ such that $\int_B f d\mu \le \frac{1}{2} \lVert f \rVert$ doesn't reduce itself to $\{\varnothing\}$ (this is because of non-atomic property), but I can't prove that it has some maximal element. This must be a consequence of Zorn's lemma, but how to show that every chain has an upper bound...?

Comment: @dissonance I'm not surprised that my hint wasn't too helpful. After posting the answer I realized that the problem is not quite that easy. I have a new answer which might be more useful. In particular, the case with a non-negative integrable $f$ reduces to the original case, by defining a new measure.

Comment: @dissonance I forgot to say: My apologies!

Comment: @Byron: You're welcome! Thank you very much for this great explanation.

Comment: @Byron: I've worked out your construction of a uniformly distributed random variable $U$. Isn't it precisely the same technique we use to prove Urysohn's lemma? Am I wrong?

Comment: @dissonance Yes, good ideas in mathematics are often recyclable!

Comment: @Byron: thanks for this careful explanation with references.

Comment: For those interested in this topic, I posted several references (at least 10) for this result and various generalizations of it in [this 25 November 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4109674).

Comment: The Math Forum link for my 25 November 2005 sci.math post no longer works, but [the google groups link](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/AIDttN3xIRU/m/rEvW0H88JBoJ) still works.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a sketch of the proof that any set of finite measure can be cut into two halves of equal measure. This proof works in the setting of a non-atomic Radon measure defined over a locally-compact Hausdorff space.

We call a (measurable) set *proper* if it has a positive, finite measure.

1. Show that every proper set has a proper subset of smaller measure.
2. Deduce that every proper set has a proper subset of arbitrarily small measure.
3. Conclude that every proper set $A$ has a subset whose measure lies in $(\mu(A)/3, \mu(A)/2]$.
4. Deduce that $A$ can be cut into two halves of equal measure.

As Byron shows above, an easy corollary is that there are subsets of $A$ of arbitrary measure in $[0,\mu(A)]$.

There's a nice generalization: let $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k$ be measures as above, let $A$ be a set of finite measure (under all of these measures), and let
$$ M = \{(\mu_1(B),\ldots,\mu_k(B)) : B \subset A \text{ is measurable wrt } \mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k\}. $$
Then $M$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: +1 for a different approach. Anyway, I'm curious: are topological properties *really* necessary? I'm just reading Bogachev's book as Byron suggests and, if I see well, I think we could do without them. Am I right? Maybe topology simplifies the proof?

Comment: I think the point of this exercise was that this setting is more general. Anyway, this background is only needed for part (1) of this argument.

Comment: I think the point in your last remark is not only that the set is compact, but that it is convex.  This is Theorem 5.5 in Rudin, Functional Analysis.

Comment: @PhoemueX Right, I actually did mean convex.