# Measure Theory: Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

[How can I find a subset of a set with "half the size" of the original?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712666/how-can-i-find-a-subset-of-a-set-with-half-the-size-of-the-original)

I am trying to solve this problem and I came across this post.  The solution using the intermediate value theorem is neat but how do we know f define in such a way is continuous?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x)=m(E\cap[-x,x])$, it follows that 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|\int_{\mathbf R}\mathbf 1_E(\mathbf 1_{[-x,x]}-\mathbf 1_{[-y,y]} )\mathrm dm\right| \leqslant \int_{\mathbf R}\left|\mathbf 1_{[-x,x]}-\mathbf 1_{[-y,y]} \right|\mathrm dm.$$
If $x\lt y$, then $\left|\mathbf 1_{[-x,x]}-\mathbf 1_{[-y,y]} \right|\leqslant\mathbf 1_{[x,y]} +\mathbf 1_{[-y,-x]}$, hence 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant 2|x-y|.$$