# Every set of finite measure can be written as the disjoint union of finitely many measurable sets with measure $\le \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $E$ has finite measure and $\epsilon>0,$ then $E$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets, each of which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

I want to use the Caratheodory condition of measurability. Let $\{I_x\}$ be a finite family of intervals such that length of each $I_{x}<\epsilon$, then $L(I_x)=m^*(E\cap I_x)+m^*(E^c\cap I_x).$ We can see $m^*(E\cap I_x)＜\epsilon$, but then I can't go on.
This problem comes from Royden's Real Analysis (page 40).

Comment: The method from [How can I find a subset of a set with “half the size” of the original?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/712666/152568) allows you to produce a subset of any given measure that is smaller than the set's measure. You can then produce your disjoint union by induction, chipping off subsets of given size $\leq\epsilon$ from $E$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E_n = E \cap [n\epsilon,(n+1)\epsilon)$, we have $\sum_k m E_k < \infty$.

Choose $K$ such that $\sum_{|k| >K} m E_k < \epsilon$. Let $E'=\cup_{|k|>K} E_k$.

Then $E_{-K},E_{-K+1},...,E_K, E'$ are disjoint, measurable and each have measure $\le \epsilon$.

Comment: How to choose Such K

Comment: You are given that the measure is finite so the sequence converges.

Comment: My understand is :since m(E) is finite then when

Comment: My understand is: since m(E) is finite then when

Comment: My understand is: since m(E) is finite the when  |k| is a large number ∪En is a small number

Comment: Review convergence of series.