# On an existence of a real-valued measurable function on a non-atomic probability measure space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $(X,E,μ)$ is a non-atomic probability  measure space. 
Let $\xi :X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. A Borel measure $\mu_{\xi}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\mu_{\xi}(X)=\mu(\xi^{-1}(X))$ for $X \in B(\mathbb{R})$ is called a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\xi$.

**Question**: Does there exists a measurable function $\xi :X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that a Borel probability measure $\mu_{\xi}$ is non-atomic?

Comment: There exists $\xi$ so that $\mu_\xi$ is any probability measure you want: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31962/how-to-split-an-integral-exactly-in-two-parts/31967#31967

Comment: @Byron Schmuland  Thank you very much for your information.

Comment: This answer has an interesting consequence: (AC). If $card(a)<c$ (here $c$ denotes the candinality of the continuum), then there does not exist a non-atomic probability measure $\mu$ defined on the power set of $a$.

Comment: gogipantsulaia@yahoo.com I specify mine comments:_$(AC)\&(MA)\&\neg (CH)$.If $card(a)<c$ (here $c$ denotes the candinality of the continuum), then there does not exist a non-atomic probability measure $μ$ defined on the power set of $a$.

Comment: Proof.Assume the contrary and $\mu$ and $a_0$ be such objects. Let $\xi: a \to R$ be a gaussian random variable on $a$. Then the cardinality of $\xi(a)$ is less then $c$ and by well known theorem it's Lebesgue measure is equal to zero. Let $B_0$ be a Borel subset of $R$ of Lebesgue measure zero which contains $\xi(a)$. Then it's Gaussian measure also will be zero and we get that $1=\mu(\{ x:\xi(x)\in R\})=\mu(\{x:\xi(x)\in B_0\})=\mu_{\xi}(B_0)=0$. This is a contradiction._